# Use translation in field components

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have trouble to use the translation in admin on rest.
I think i don't really understand how it's work

For example I cannot use translation in this case:

```
<FunctionField
    label="some.label"
    render={(record, translate) => translate('some.translation')}
/>
```

I have this error: `uncaught at handleFetch TypeError: translate is not a function`

Someone would be able to help me on this?

Comment: This is not how to use the translation feature please read the docs. 

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Translation.html

Comment: thank your response but the doc doesn't really help in this point.

finally works when I use props.translate

Comment: @sebdec If you figured out how it works, considering [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a component on the render function.

```
<FunctionField render={
   (record) =>
      <Component label={translate('record.to_translate')} /> 
} />
```